# Highcharts context menu hidden behind series

Tags: highcharts

The context menu is hidden behind the series when the bar chart series spans across the entire chart.  How can I get the menu to not be hidden behind the series?

http://jsfiddle.net/kadams/uy05zby3/2/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
  "chart": {
    "type": "bar",
    "zoomType": "x"
  },
  "title": {
    "text": ""
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "title": {
      "text": ""
    },
    "categories": [
      "A",
      "B",
      "C"
    ]
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "series": {
      "stacking": "percent",
      "pointPadding": 0.2,
      "borderWidth": 0,
      "animation": false
    }
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "name": "Bacon",
      "data": [
        36.4,
        18.9,
        17.5
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Pork Chops",
      "data": [
        105,
        93.7,
        108.8
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Ham",
      "data": [
        32.7,
        30.7,
        34.2
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two solutions for your case:

- display button in front of the series: http://jsfiddle.net/uy05zby3/7/

  ```
  events: {
      load: function() {
          if(!this.options.chart.forExport) {
              this.exportSVGElements[0].toFront(); 
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- make space for the button: http://jsfiddle.net/uy05zby3/5/

  ```
  "chart": {
      "type": "bar",
      "zoomType": "x",
      "marginTop": 30 // make more space on top  edge
  },
  ```

Comment: Excellent, Thanks @Pawel Fus, the first solution you suggested is perfect!

Comment: @Fus, for some reason this first fiddle you shared  http://jsfiddle.net/uy05zby3/4/ is not working now (but it was before).  `this.exportSVGElements` is undefined when clicking on an exporting option from the menu.  Not sure why.  Any ideas?

Comment: That's really strange.   I tried it in chrome, safari, and firefox with the same error.  I opened an issue on it: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4272.

Comment: Well, now I should close that ticket, because it works perfectly fine for me..  ;)  Make sure you have included `exporting.js` file.

Comment: [Here's a video](https://youtu.be/hr-GjDtxJok) of the same issue happening in chrome, safari, and firefox.  `exporting.js` is included. The only thing that's different from your demo on the jsfiddle is the console.log showing `this.exportSVGElements`.

Comment: Oh my, I'm blind. Probably day without coffee isn't the best idea ;) OF course, there will be an error when exporting image, because chart is duplicated but without that buttons. That means `exportSVGElements` will be undefined. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the height value set in the div,

try the following

```
#container {
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 800px;
    min-height: 350px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
```

[fiddle link :)](http://jsfiddle.net/uy05zby3/3/)

Answer (score -2):

It provides margin so that no overlay of menu happpens
hope this us helpful